# How to save Python results in 5 txt files

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I want to save results in 5 txt files. My results from my code is

```
14R2
14Rt
14R8
1402
140t
1408
14a2
14at
14a8
1dR2
```

I want to write in first file

```
14R2
14Rt
```

the second one

```
14R8
1402
```

And so on to 5. 
This is my code for 1 file and they work perfect.

```
import itertools
f = open("first_file.txt", "w")
somelists = [
['1','K','5'],
['4','d','1'],
['R','0','a'],
['2','t','8'],
    ]
for element in itertools.islice(itertools.product(*somelists),1 , 10):
    print(''.join(element), file=f)
f.close()
```

I get advice from one power user here Kevin and he gave me this code

```
filenames = ["my_file_{}.txt".format(i) for i in range(5)]

for filename in filenames:
with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write(some_stuff())
```

But when I tried to implement I get error "unexpected EOF while parsing"

This is what I tried

```
import itertools
filenames = ["my_file_{}.txt".format(i) for i in range(5)]
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
            somelists = [

['1','K','5'],
['4','d','1'],
['R','0','a'],
['2','t','8'],
    ]



for element in itertools.islice(itertools.product(*somelists),1 , 5):
     file.write(''.join(element())
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you know how to write one file? so do it five times and you got it

Comment: Yes I know how to write one. But that is not the same like 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to the problems indicated by Andrew T., you can't call `file.write` if you're no longer in the `with` block that opened the file. The file closes itself at the end of the with block, so you get `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`.

So you should move your `write` call inside the with block. While we're moving things around, Move the `somelists` definition outside of the `for filename in filenames:` loop, since there's no point assigning it more than once. It will also be more efficient to call `product` only once, and use `next` to extract items from it.

```
import itertools

num_files = 5
elements_per_file = 2


somelists = [
    ['1','K','5'],
    ['4','d','1'],
    ['R','0','a'],
    ['2','t','8'],
]

items = ("".join(element) for element in itertools.product(*somelists))

for i in range(num_files):
    filename = "my_file_{}.txt".format(i)
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        for j in range(elements_per_file):
            file.write(next(items) + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin. This is awesome. But for me it's very important to work with `itertools.islice for element in itertools.islice(itertools.product(*somelists),0 , 10):` When I add like this `items = ("".join(element) for element in itertools.islice(itertools.product(*somelists),0 , 10):` I get  error " invalid syntax "

Comment: Thanks again I add `items = ("".join(element) for element in itertools.islice(itertools.product(*somelists),0 , 10))` and works.

Comment: Strange, I wouldn't expect `islice` to have any impact here. If you're worried that `product` will calculate all 81 possibilities even though you only want the first ten, you don't have to worry about that - the generator expression will calculate only as many values as are needed to fulfill each `next` call. That's the case regardless of whether you use islice or not. But I guess `islice` isn't hurting anything, so if you really want to use it then feel free.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing parentheses:

```
file.write(''.join(element())
```

should be

```
file.write(''.join(element()))
```

Unexpected EOF while parsing means that a code block hasn't been completed.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get this error TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: Get rid of the () in element(). Should just be element.

Comment: When I remove () I get error " ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."